# Strokerform multiselect field validation in ZF2

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

I have a form set up in my ZF2 application and I have configured the `Strokerform` (https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-form) validation to work for the most part. The problem is that I have one multiselect field (enchanced with `Chosen` library (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) and everytime I try to submit the form I get one error message 2 times : `The input was not found in the haystack` .

I have written a custom validator for that field, which extends the InArray validator:

```
<?php

namespace Vacations\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\InArray;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Recipients extends InArray implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{    

protected $services;
protected $options;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $this->services = $serviceLocator;
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->services;
}

public function __construct($options = null)
{

    $this->options = $options;

    $this->setServiceLocator($options['serviceLocator']);

    $table = $this->services->get('Vacations\Model\ManagerTable');

    $select = $table->getTableGateway()->select();
    $array = array_column($select->toArray(), 'id');

    $options = $options + array('haystack' => $array);

    parent::__construct($options);
}

}
```

Added it as a filter to the form:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'recipients',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    new Recipients( array(
                        'model' => 'ManagerTable',
                        'serviceLocator' => $this->getServiceLocator()
                    )),
        )));
```

Any ideas how to set the `Strokerform` to validate the sent data with the information, which I get from the database in the validator or disable the validation for this field at all?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the developer of `StrokerForm`, I don't have time to dive into your particular issue with the multiselect right now.

For the time being you could skip automatic generation of the jquery validate rules for the element as follows. You should set this option on the element, not on the inputFilter.

```
$recipients->setOption('strokerform-exclude', true);
```

Als see the [manual](https://github.com/bramstroker/zf2-form#excluding-elements-from-clientside-validation).

Now you can add your own validation logic or rules to jquery validate for the recipients field.

Comment: Well apparently Zend Framework sees if you have disabled the validation on a field and sets it`s own in_array validation. I had to add the option `'disable_inarray_validator' => true` inside the RequestForm where I create the field to disable this validation.

Now the only problem is that I send an array of values from my multiselect field and try to validate it. I guess that the error comes from the fact that it tries to match not each element from the first array with each element from the haystack, but the array as a whole with each element from the haystack. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Fixed my problem by overriding the isValid() method in my custom validator:

`public function isValid($value)
    {
        if(is_array($value)){
            $flag = true;
            foreach($value as $element){
                if(!parent::isValid($element)){
                    $flag = false;
                }
            }
            if($flag){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        parent::isValid($value);
    }`

P.S. Sorry for the bad formating.